# a curious approach to differentiability

Tags: analysis, derivatives

Given $f:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ , suppose that exists a function $h:\mathbb{R}^{m}\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^{m},\mathbb{R}^{n})$ such that for every smooth function $g:\mathbb{R}^{l}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $f(g(x)) $ is smooth and
$ h(g(x))\circ g'(x)= (f\circ g)'(x)$.
Does It follow that $f$ is smooth and $f'=h$?

Comment: Sort your brackets out first please.

Comment: What happens if you let $g(x)=x$?

Comment: you don't get to choose g arbitrarily because it is not always guaranteed that $f\circ g$ is differentiable

Answer (score 1):

I’m interpreting your question as the following; if $h$ satisfies the chain rule equation for $f$ any of its possible parameterizations, is $h’ = f’$? The answer is no, but up to an additive constant yes.

If $h’$ satisfies the desired equation for any such $g$, it in particular satisfies it for $g(x) = x$. Then your equation specializes to $h’(x) = f’(x)$. The solutions to this are precisely $f(x) + c$.

Notice that additive constants do work. Replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x) + c$, we have $(f(g(x)) + c)’ = f’(g(x))g’(x)$, as desired.

Edit: As has been pointed out, once you fixed your formatting you didn’t want $h’$ to satisfy the desired equation but h itself. In that case, the solution is even simpler; the $g(x) = x$ case forces $h(x) = f’(x)$.

Comment: The interpretation is not correct

Comment: I’ve fixed it to answer your original question at the bottom.

Comment: First of all you don't get to choose g arbitrarily because it is not always guaranteed that f∘g
 is differentiable. Secondly the question is whether f is differentiable and f'=h

Comment: At least, f need not be differentiable everywhere. Letting $f = |x|, h = sgn(x)$, the functions $g(x)$ that satisfy $|g(x)|$ differentiable everywhere are precisely those functions $g(x)$ such that anytime $g(x)$ changes sign, it does so with 0 derivative. For any such function, $|g(x)|$ is differentiable everwhere also, and $|g(x)|' = sgn(g(x))g'(x)$. For example, $g(x) = x^3$. But $f(x)$ is clearly not differentiable everywhere. Though this isn't a great counterexample because $h$ is its derivative wherever it does turn out to be differentiable so I'd have to think a bit more.

Comment: Btw, if you were to object that sign(x) is not defined at 0, I believe we can define it to be anything at 0 and the above example should still serve as a counterexample.

Comment: I've modified the question. This was probably my original thought but I didn't write it properly at first.